# php update query using prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing updation of table using following prepared statements as follows:

```
 $query = " UPDATE signup SET name=?,password=?,verify_key=? WHERE email=? ";
 $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$dname,$password,$verify_key,$email);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
```

But it is giving error on which I am stuck for long time:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in somefile.php on line 75

Structure of table in database is as follow:

```
mysql> desc signup;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| sid        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| verify_key | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| active     | bit(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Note :** I printed $dname,$password,$verify_key,$email. All printed correct string values.

Entire PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once("connection.php");

$dname=$_POST['dname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

if(empty($dname) || empty($email) || empty($password))
  die("Enter correct details.");

$password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // generate hash for password
$verify_key = password_hash(RandomString(),PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // generate hash for verification key

/* RandomString() generates random string */
function RandomString($length = 32) {
      $randstr;
      //our array add all letters and numbers if you wish
      $chars = array(
          'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p',
          'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
          '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
          'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
      for ($rand = 0; $rand <= $length; $rand++) {
          $random = rand(0, count($chars) - 1);
          $randstr .= $chars[$random];
      }
      return $randstr;
}  // function RandomString()  over

/*  Mail Sending Code */
function sendMail($email,$verify_key){
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Something';
$mail_link='https://127.0.0.1/rs/signupCheck.php?email='.$email.'&key='.$verify_key;
$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<a href='> Click this link to verify your account </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'From: Something <Something>';
$res = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
return $res;  //check officially mail is sent or not
}  // function sendMain() ends


// check if email already exists in database
$query = " SELECT active FROM signup WHERE email=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($dbactive);
if($stmt->fetch()){     // email is present in DB
if($dbactive==1){        // status=1
  $stmt->close();
  die("Account already created. Try forget passwod if you can't access it.");
}
else{
  /* Record is already present with status=0 , override all the details */
  if(sendMail($email,$verify_key)) {  // send mail first then update DB
     $query = " UPDATE `signup` SET `name`=?,`password`=?,`verify_key`=? WHERE `email`=? ";
     $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
     $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$dname,$password,$verify_key,$email);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
     die("We sent you verification link on mail. Click it to verify !!!");
  }
  else {
    die("Mail sending failed. Try again !!!");
  }
}
}      // email already present with either status=1 or status=0
else { // Insert account details in DB , nothing is present in DB for user
     if(sendMail($email,$verify_key)) {  // send mail first then update DB
       $query = "INSERT INTO signup (sid,name,email,password,verify_key,active)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
       $stmt->bind_param("issssi",$fixed_sid='',$dname,$email,$password,$verify_key,$fixed_active=0);
        /* Notice $fixed_sid and $fixed_active , it is needed
           you can't have fixed values in bind_param
        */
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->close();
       die("We sent you verification link on mail. Click it to verify !!!");
     }
     else {
       die("Mail sending failed. Try again !!!");
     }
}    // first time data entry in DB
?>
```

Comment: You prepare statment return false  .. could be you have some wrong column name  .. check for error  ..

Comment: You need to pass the variables by reference.

Comment: @cybermonkey problem is in `prepare` not in `bind_param`.

Comment: @u_mulder I know, the variables still need to be passed by reference regardless. The query should also be properly formatted to prevent MySQLi interpreting table/column names as reserved words.

Comment: And what reserved word do you see here?

Comment: I already removed my vote. `password` is a keyword but not "reserved".

Comment: which driver are you using and how are you connecting? is the connection successful? you don't seem to be checking for failure even in the prepare statement. From the php docs it also appears that for mysqli the `prepare()` and `bind_param()` functions are run on the statement object which is obtained using `stmt_init()`.

Comment: @inarilo Yes,connection is successful.

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't know what is getting wrong here. That's why given entire table definition and whole prepared statements.

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: @inarilo I am not sure about this how to check it? By the way I have one block in same page to insert data in same table and it is working fine. This is more strange for me.

Comment: @chris85 yes I made else block as well. one If statement executed.

Comment: I think preparing works fine. But their is some problem with binding.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you Chris . $stmt->close() needs to be in both if and else block. Problem solved. Great catch by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `$stmt->close();` before your next `mysqli` interaction.

```
if(sendMail($email,$verify_key)) {  // send mail first then update DB
    $stmt->close();
    $query = " UPDATE `signup` SET `name`=?,`password`=?,`verify_key`=? WHERE `email`=? ";
```

or you might just always want to execute the `close` after you're finished with your previous `mysql` interaction.

e.g.:

```
$query = " SELECT active FROM signup WHERE email=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($dbactive);
$stmt->close();
```

and remove the `$stmt->close();` from the `if`. I've never seen official documentation on this but I've seen other threads were this was an underlying issue. The manual page itself actual almost states the opposite:

> So, while explicitly closing open connections and freeing result sets **is optional**, doing so is recommended.

that `is optional` is false (... in my experience, I also primarily use PDO).

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue in my query and this line of code help me to diagnose my error

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

here is reference may be it help you

https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection